# Add jQuery Gallery in Flash AS2

Tags: jquery, flash, gallery, actionscript-2, flash-8

The question is simple. I dont know about the answer.
Is it possible to use a jQuery gallery in a flash 8 document made with ActionScript2, and how?
Just point me a direction.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, while it is possible to get AS2 to communicate with jQuery, it can be awkward and generally ill-advised. It is not possible to have jQuery use a Flash component directly and vice versa. If communication is sufficient, however, you will have to look into the [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=Part2_AS2_LangRef_1.html) class.

By the way, AS2 is outdated enough that it took more than one try to find the right page.

Comment: lol i get it but the whole site is in as2 so it would be very difficult for me to translate it. Thank you for your answer